# Pop from stack using linked list method

Tags: java, stack, push

I'm trying to pop and push numbers to a stack using linked lists, i've managed to remove the number from the beginning of the stack in the code i shared but how/where the removed node is stored for later use(for a calculator)

I tried to declare a variable called deletedData before the if statement but then my IDE tells me this variable is already defined in the scope.
Any insight to where i am mistaken here would be greatly appreciated. I am new to java and looking to learn :)

```
public class List
{
    private ListNode head = null;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class List
     * Create a head
     */
    public List()
    {
    }


    public void addToList(int number)
    {
        ListNode  newOne;

        newOne = new ListNode(number);
        newOne.setNext(head);

        head = newOne;
    }

    public ListNode removeFirstNode()
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        } else {
            // Move the head pointer to the next node
            ListNode deletedData = head;
            head = head.getNext();

        }
        return head;

public class ListNode
{
    // instance variables
    private int number;
    private ListNode next;


    public ListNode(int number)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        this.number = number;
        this.next = null;
    }


    public ListNode getNext()
    {
        return next;
    }



    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }



    public void setNext(ListNode next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }
```

Comment: You need to post your solution.

Comment: In your `removeFirstNode` you're returning the second item.  You need to `return deletedData` which is the first item, then your `head.next()` becomes `head` (which you're doing).  As for your main question, you need to do a `popped = list.removeFistNode()` and then use it there.

Comment: its returning ListNode@5b480cf9. etc. how do i see the ints stored in the list?